# Finding replacement parts for DIY home repairs

Tags: repair

Not sure this is a good place for this question. Kindly, migrate if it is wrong.

I am looking for parts for JBL E40BT. can't find part numbers or where to order them. In general, how do you find parts for a specific device? Is there a method you are using or is it individual for any device?

Comment: You're not sure whether this is a home improvement question? I am. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great Question! You are looking to improve your workflow by upgrading your skills in troubleshooting/repair.

Generally you want to find the **service manual** or **repair manual** for the item you are trying to fix. For complex repairs or diagnostics these are essential to a successful repair operation. They will contain all the parts diagrams, part numbers, procedures, and diagnostic codes you could possibly need. These can be difficult to find if the manufacturer wants to monopolize the service and repair of their item. Alternatively you may find that the service manual is available but may have to pay a fee to access or download it. In general obtaining the service manual is the most important step in any repair procedure so I am glad you asked this question.

Unfortunately headphones are either too simple, too cheap, or not profitable to be designed as serviceable so there will be no official service/repair documentation nor official source of replacement parts.

iFixit.com is an excellent source of repair guides for consumer electronics. They have step-by-step guides accompanied with photos for everything from xbox consoles to ipods to cell phones. This site even sells specific replacement parts for such repair projects. Typically the more popular a product is the more likely there will be user-generated guide available.

Although this specific pair of headphones is listed on iFixit.com, no repair guide has been generated. The last possible source of information is YouTube or another third party site where someone has made a guide or provided some info on the repair. If you still cannot find anything useful you are on your own. Before you even attempt the repair, however make sure there are replacement parts available at a reasonable price.

For replacement parts one trick I learned while repairing my Beats By Dre solo headphones (they were a gift....) is to search eBay for the exact item you want to fix and select "for parts or repair" as a search filter. Find a broken pair of the same headphones with the part you need intact. Hopefully you can find something sensibly priced. As a bonus you will have a surplus of replacement parts after you harvest the broken item for the part you need. You can also search eBay for the exact part you need. You need to describe the part as best you can and tweak the words in your search multiple times until you find the results you want. For some reason in my experience, the exact replacement part(s) can be listed at very high unfair prices.

There is a good supply of replacement parts for JBL E40BT on eBay so hopefully you can find what you need. Good luck on your repair!